How to reconcile the effect of my time magic spell with my timeline
Magic is able to achieve its mystical effects through its Pleroma. Basically, Pleromas are magical and non-physical locations and objects that serve as the sources of power for magic. Each Pleroma is connected to a specific element of magic. In this case, time magic derives its power from the Time Pleroma of the River of Time.
The River of Time represents the sequence of the past, present, and future in its totality as a river. It flows right, representing the irreversible direction of time. There is only one River so alternate timelines cannot exist. The River's waters are categorized into Past Water, Present Water, and Future Water; each respectively represents the past, present, and future. Past Waters determine Present Waters and Present Waters determine Future Waters; in other words, the past determines the present and the present determines the future.
Rank 8 Time Mages have a series of spells unique to their rank called Ouroboros. This spell series creates an Ouroboros within the River of Time that swims along with the flow of the Present Waters. The River of Time annihilates everything that interacts with it but the Ouroboros are serpentine, magical constructs designed to survive and thrive in its Waters. However, this durability mostly extends to Present Waters. We'll focus on three spells.

Upstream Jump: The Ouroboros devours the mage's soul, reverses its course, and jumps upstream. This sends the consciousness of the mage back to the past. It's a mental form of time travel. The Ouroboros will get annihilated in the process of jumping to Past Waters. Consequently, this spell cannot be accompanied with other spells.
Upstream Ecdysis: The Ouroboros gulps Past Water and turns the mage into a state of themselves from their past. The mage in the present borrows from their past self. The more Past Water it gulp, the further into the past it can tap into but the more damaged it becomes.
Downstream Ecdysis: The Ouroboros gulps Future Water and turns the mage into a state of themselves from their future. The mage in the present borrows from their future self. The more Future Water it gulp, the further into the future it can tap into but the more damaged it becomes.

Consider Timeline A and Timeline B. Timeline A represents the timeline before the Rank 8 Time Mage uses Ouroboros: Upstream Jump and Timeline B represents the modified timeline after the spell's usage. When the time mage in Timeline B casts Ouroboros: Upstream Ecdysis, they gain power from their past self with no issues. However, when they cast Ouroboros: Downstream Ecdysis, they gain power from their future self from Timeline A instead of Timeline B.
As established, Present Waters determine Future Waters. With the time mage's upstream jump,  the Present Waters are changed therefore Future Waters must change completely in response because of the butterfly effect. To further add, there is only one River of Time so alternate and branching timelines cannot exist.
How do I justify this seeming contradiction without allowing branching timelines or fundamentally changing the spells?

The easiest way to get rid of time paradoxes is simply to get rid of time travel. Limit the capstone skills of time mages to manipulating the personal experience of time (slowing down, speeding up) or do non-interactive things like postcognition.

How literally are you taking the time-as-a-river metaphor? There might be only one time stream (riverbed), but malleable sequences of events within it (the water).  Imagining somebody stepping onto the 'shore' of the present, they would be able to watch their present drift off into the future while the the slice of time in front of them gradually changes to some other 'present', so when they step back in they're actually in a slightly different time than the one they left...?

We are not a brainstorming site.

I think this depends on how literally you take the metaphor of River of Time. If Time really, genuinely works like a river, the changes do not propagate instantly.
Consider this, you have 3 piers, each 3 feet apart. 3 swimmers jump of the piers, into the river, one of each. Even though the Upstream jumper hits the water that "precedes" the Middle/Present water, the waves and splash the Upstream Jumper creates doe not reach the Present jumper until after they already are in the water. A second or two later they do, and the Past changes the Present, and the Present changes the Future, but there is enough lag/delay to both time travel AND have past determinism, which would mix.
So you can consider that the River of Time also has its own "Meta-time" which is how much delay there is between the past being changed and it affecting the future,and during that delay, you can squeeze extra time-changes.
So, fittingly, the trick to use Time Magic is good time management. If you keep a tight schedule of your time-jumps, it is possible to make them mesh without conflict; but the closer you try to squeeze them, the more chaotic the outcome.

Actually, with this metaphor, changes do not propagate at all like a time traveller would think.
You are like a leaf, floating down the river of time. Your present is the waters right around you.
If you jump upstream the waters will look similar to the ones you have seen, but its not the same water, and its waves and ripples will be somewhat different. You can make changes but those will never catch up to that original leaf, its long gone downstream.

To shamelessly steal a line from Tenet "What's happened, happened." i.e. you can't change events that led you to the present, you can only act to make those events happen exactly as they have. This is an expression of the impossibility of creating causality paradoxes. In your case:

During an Upstream Jump the Mage travels back in time and tries to change the time he came from only to find when he gets there that his actions all led him straight back where he came from.

Upstream Ecdysis doesn't really present issues that I can see. The mage is in the present using the past to create the future, that's what you might call the standard order of operation.

If Downstream Ecdysis can be used to know the course of the future one would only want to do so if they wanted to spend the rest of their life deeply bored and frustrated, knowing the future and unable to change it. Borrowing future abilities/powers doesn't change the course of the future, it sets them.


In this model while the Mage may think that Present Waters affect Future Waters in reality the Future Waters have always been there and are changeless, their course predetermined by some overarching fate and all the magic that will ever be thrown into the mix actually makes no difference at all.

This Upstream Jump model doesn't really track for me. Even if you resolve the personal paradox of backward time travel, things the time traveler does while in the past will still surely affect everything else. For instance, if an office worker jumps back a month and blows up a gas station, they may still be an office worker in the present but that gas station will be replaced by a crater. The only way this model works is if time traveling creates an isolated timestream that ceases to exist when the traveler returns to the present, and OP has already stated the River wouldn't tolerate that.

Pretty sure Tenet didn’t come up with the line “what’s happened happened” but I get what you’re saying.

@Abion47, if an office worker jumps back a month and blows up a gas station, that means that at the time of departure, there was a month-old crater at the former location of a gas station.  If there is no crater, then the attempt to blow up the gas station will fail for reasons that are entirely consistent with the state of the universe at the time of departure.

@Abion47 Exactly what Mark said.

@controlgroup You're probably right, I rather doubt that the movie coined the phrase as well, that's just where I ended up pulling it from.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle

In software development, source control has similar problems, that is called merge conflicts. In essence:
                 /--- timeline A---\
Starting point -+                   +---- merged events
                 \--- timeline B---/

Goal is to avoid the explosion of the concurrent timelines, by mixing the variants into a single one.
Probably nature would try to do it on the least destructive way. If there is some direct contradiction among the timelines - like, you die on one but not on another - then we have a merge conflict.
Most likely, in these point, some unnatural happen if the wizard does not intervene to determine the best intermediate solution (like you do not die, but some wonder saves you from death in the last moment).
Some weird wizardry might even try to cause merge conflicts in order to cause otherways unreachable events (like convert you to an undead without hard necromancy skills).

I love this answer! To my memory, I have never seen something like this used before.

@InHocSigno Thanks! Funny thing is, under "merge" we could actually understand some quantum field-level "merge" in hard physics. But that is not practical, maybe a planet-sized nuclear explosion is not even impossible. It should be, imho, some solipsism-based "merge", i.e. the common point of the multiple timelines, but on a way, as if the observers see it the least uncommon.

That's more or less how I was visualizing it myself. It's like how most time-travel stories ignore the issue of celestial bodies' movement.

Premonition
Consider what is being really moved across time: Information
It is unclear from your question whether the mage is allowed to move his body through time or if he is just able to move into his own body at different times. This answer assumes the latter.
The spells to jump to the past can be reduced to a form of premonition. By jumping back in time, the future mage is bringing back a vision of a possible future. You can avoid any inconsistencies by framing the power that way. While your mage's body is part of the time current, his consciousness reaches out into possible futures using the ouroboros spells.

Or put another way, divination in a single timeline has exactly the same problems with inconsistency as does time travel, if we can use information from the future to change that future.

If there is only a single timeline, then any interactions between Past-Present-Future are deterministic. That means if a Ouroboros gulps water from the Future, the water from the Future was already "missing" some water, and Ouroboros actions only matched that occurrence. A case of Past waters going "missing" is then explained by it appearing on Present waters, as it was always meant to be.
In this scenario, the timeline is predetermined and Fate exists. Going against Fate would be breaking this River of Time into smaller branches, and that sounds like a nice goal for an obssessed mage.
You could also make small changes to the spells, in that by making the Ouroboros gulp Past Water, and as such "Borrow Power" from the past, your past self actually felt the sudden loss of power. A common mage just felt sick, or it could be a rare disease in mages. A genius time mage could understand, and maybe even feel, that their power was sent to the future, and that knowledge would also change his own actions moving forward. It would also "prove" that said mage has great potential for time magic or similar things.
Sending power to the future could also be a thing, like sending it 10 years to the future as part of a plan for revenge or for when a specific event should happen. Different from borrowing, you lend power as a means of investment, out of current choice. Like sending excess power from your youth so you can use on your old age, hoping to survive longer when you are old.
And then again, all of this being predetermined by fate, everything being connected.

Doesn't necessarily need to be pre-determined either.  Think of it like setting a spreadsheet program to do cyclic calculations until the values stabilize.  If the mage throws something through time that changes what happens, then the calculation gets run again and repeat until you find a state where the mage does the same thing every time through.
